# Return promise result from method

Tags: javascript, promise, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to create a new Id for a notification using the `getAllIds()` method supplied by the `$cordovaLocalNotification` plugin.

I have a `notify` Class which has a method for creating a new Id and a subsequent method for creating a notification as below:

```
var notify = {
  latestId: function() {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.getAllIds().then(function(result){
      return result.length;
    })
  },
  setNotification: function(show) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: notify.latestId,
        title: show.name + " is out today!",
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Where I try and assign the result using `id: notify.latestId` It seems to be en empty promise object or something. I've tried loads of different design patterns but I think I am missing something fundamental. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Whole factory for good measure.

```
.factory('Notifications', function($cordovaLocalNotification,   $ionicPlatform) {

    var notify = {
  alertTime: function() {
    t = new Date();
    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);
    return t;
  },
  latestId: function() {
    var newId;
    $cordovaLocalNotification.getAllIds().then(function(result){
      console.log('Get all ids: ' + result) //Returned 2nd: 'Get all ids: 1,0,4,5,3,2'
      newId = result.length;
      console.log('New id: ' + newId);//Returned 3rd: 'New id: 6'
    });
    console.log('New id: ' + newId); //Returned first: 'New id: undefined'
    return newId;
  },
  clearAll: function() {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.clearAll();
  },
  setNotification: function(show) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: notify.latestId(), // undefined
        title: show.name + " is out today!",
        firstAt: notify.alertTime()
      });
    });
  }
};
return {
  setNotification: function(show){
    notify.setNotification(show);
  },
  clearAll: function(){
    notify.clearAll()
  },
  setAll: function() {
    console.log('Set all');
  }
};
})
```

Comment: `latestId` is function that return promise, posibly you need `id: notify.latestId(),`

Comment: @Grundy Removed as a question and added as a comment as per your requirement ;-) "I think you need to include parentheses to call the actual function latestId()..." like Grundy said ;)

Does that make sense?

Comment: Does "notify.alertTime()" have a valid value?

Comment: Can you provide the output of result too pls

Comment: Yeh, it returns a time 10 seconds from when it runs. e.g. Sat Oct 24 2015 12:27:03 GMT+0100 (BST)

Comment: Bit fiddly to debug on the phone, i'm console logging out:           `console.log(notify.latestId());`
`console.log(notify.alertTime());` and getting 'undefined' and 'Sat Oct 24 2015 12:27:03 GMT+0100 (BST)'

Comment: you simple return nothing from `latestId` function :-) change to `latestId: function() {
      return $cordovaLocalNotification...` and all should work

Comment: Ah yeh oops, result of messing around with it so much! Still though no joy... I have updated the bottom code block in my question to reflect this update and what the console.log() is now returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct approach but it fixed my problem. I removed the latestId() method and wrapped the promise around the setNotification() code so that it doesn't try and create a notification until the promise is resolved. See below:

```
var notify = {
  alertTime: function() {
    t = new Date();
    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);
    return t;
  },
  clearAll: function() {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.clearAll();
  },
  setNotification: function(show) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.getAllIds().then(function(result){
        var newId = result.length;
        $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
          id: newId,
          title: show.name + " is out today!",
          firstAt: notify.alertTime()
        });
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to localize vars ... `var t = new Date();`